# fcm-node tells that certificate is expired, but ist not true

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification to ios device through phonegap/firebase, using fcm-node and I get this message:

```
{"results":[{"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-apns-credentials","message":"**A message targeted to an iOS device could not be sent because the required APNs SSL certificate was not uploaded or has expired. Check the validity of your development and production certificates**."}}.
```

The big problem is that my certificate is not expired, and I tryied creating new ones and get the same message.

Does anyone knows what I am possibly doing wrong ?

Another point is that I dont have a Mac computer, I am developing this app on ubuntu. Does that makes some diference ?

Comment: check this  https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors  "A message targeted to an iOS device could not be sent because the required APNs SSL certificate was not uploaded or has expired. Check the validity of your development and production certificates." Have you uploaded the new certificate in firebase server  after recreation?

Comment: Yes!!! Another wierd point is that in the firebase console shows that my cert expiration date will be in 2018.